# Cannot find what is wrong in CS50 Pset4 reflect?

Tags: c, cs50

I have written this code for reflect, and when I use check50 I got the following:

```
:( reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
    expected "0 0 255\n255 0...", not "0 0 255\n0 0 2..."

:( reflect correctly filters 1x3 image
    expected "0 0 255\n0 255...", not "0 0 255\n0 255..."

:) reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image

:( reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 80 90\n40 5...", not "70 80 90\n40 5..."

:( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "100 110 120\n7...", not "100 110 120\n7..."
```

Yet these numbers seem to be the same...

Here is my reflect function:

```
/ Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //Cycle through rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {   //Cycle through columns
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {   //Swap the current cell with oppsite cell.
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][width - j - 1].rgbtGreen;
        }    
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: Note that your swaps are not *actually* swaps, but just assignments.  Since you are reading from and writing to the same image, you end up copying one half of the image, reversed, onto the second half.  The second half is then re-copied back onto the first half, but since it is symmetrical at this point, it does nothing.  You probably want to only go up to `width/2` and do a true swap for each pixel.

Comment: Take a piece of paper. Make a 2x2 image. For each step in your code, draw how the image changes. You'll soon see major problems with your code

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it so others can find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to point out that check50 is only showing a very small subset of the pixels; just because you got the first 2-3 pixels reflected correctly doesn't mean all of them are right.

That said, here are three suggestions to improve your code:

1. Your goal is to move one half on an image to the other half. Therefore, you won't want to iterate through ALL the columns, since as 0x5453 said that would cause you to just reflect twice thus leaving the image the same as it was,but half of them. You can do this by setting `j < round(width / 2.0)` in your second for loop.
2. Remember from David Malan's lecture that you need a temporary cup to switch the contents of two cups. So you should set a temp variable to be the original pixel, then set the original pixel to the one on the other side, then set the one on the other side to be the temp variable. This will switch the original pixel with the one on the other side; i.e. a reflection.
3. Since you're just switching pixels, you don't need to bother with the individual colors; you can just deal with `image[i][j]` instead of `image[i][j].rgbtRed` and all the other colors. In the other parts that involve color distortion, you'll need to deal with the colors.